# Изменился таймаут для отмены голосов за комментарии?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии

Раньше можно было отменить плюс комментарию в течение некоторого, довольно продолжительного, времени. Сейчас не могу убрать поставленный ошибочно плюс уже через несколько секунд. Изменили? А зачем?

---

похоже, там какой-то баг. Если поставить плюс и ничего не делать, то можно отменить довольно долго. Если поставить плюс и тут же обновить страницу или написать свой комментарий, то уже нельзя отменить, хоть там даже одна секунда прошла.

Comment: Не знаю зачем (уменьшить нагрузку на сервера?), но мне тоже кажется, что зря. Я бывает прочитав комментарий и поставив лайк вдруг через пять секунд до меня доходит, что нет, не стоило добавлять плюс. И я не очень хочу думать над комментариями долго и вдумчиво -- мне проще совсем отказаться от простановки голосов на комментариях. Увы.

Comment: похоже, там какой-то баг. Если поставить плюс и ничего не делать, то можно отменить довольно долго. Если поставить плюс и тут же обновить страницу, то уже нельзя отменить.

Comment: Гм, тогда я например не уверен, что это баг свежий - мне кажется, что я никогда не перезагружал страницу перед отменой комментария.

Comment: перезагрузка всего лишь пример. Можно написать свой комментарий и тоже уже нельзя отменить плюс. Пока я писал этот текст я мог отменить плюс вашему первому комментарию, но как только я его отправил, то сразу не могу.